# Why is the Jenkins Git Plugin using old parameter values when being triggered by SCM tool

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We use a Jenkins build server to build our software after pushes to several Git repositories.

Since we went to some code reorganization recently I tried to set up a more sophisticated build pipeline, building each of our products (a Git repository each) in the order of their dependencies.

Each job triggers the execution of the subsequent project's build job passing the `$GIT_BRANCH` to the next job.

The whole pipeline works pretty well, I start the build of the first project in `origin/master` and project 2, 3 and 4 get build in master. I start in another branch, the subsequent projects switch to this branch.

I use the Git Parameter Plug-in to do the Branch-Selection and pass it to the Git branch refs. The default value is an empty string.

Unfortunately this whole setup breaks the push hooks from Gitblit. While Jenkins still reports that the concrete project was triggered to check the SCM, builds only starts if the commit was in the branch selected for the last manual build.

Checking the Git poll log I see that only the previously selected branch was checked for changes.

From my still basic understanding of all of this I would guess, that the SCM poll trigger uses the last "known" value, not the defaultValue of the parameter. Is this a bug in Jenkins, the plugin or my configuration. Has anybody else accomplished such a dual-use pipeline?

**edit**: I tried "**" as default value, same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a not so clean solution for the problem. I added further build jobs, which do nothing but sitting on the SCM and trigger the real projects afterwards. They pass the GIT commit ID that was "built" to the next job.

Here is an example:

```
projectA_trigger
    Freestyle Project
    GIT Repository configured
    Build triggert by SCM
    Post-Build-Action Trigger parameterized build of projectA, submit built GIT commit ID
projectA
    Maven-Project
    GIT repository configured
    Build NOT triggered by SCM
    Post-Build-Action Trigger parameterized build of projectB...
```

I created a trigger project for every former main project, now SCM changes trigger builds in the right branches and use the pipeline.

That works but feels a bit hacky, so if you have a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Please consider migrating the "answer" part of your question to this answer post.